# Driver Installed - Still cannot use OleDB reader

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, oledb

I have code in a Provider-Hosted App for SharePoint which calls the *OleDBDataReader* class in order to parse a .xslx file. In my development environment, the following exception appeared until I installed [this driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

`The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine`. I have moved to pre-production, and the error has popped up again even though the admins of the IIS box are swearing back and forth that the driver is installed. They've sent me a screenshot of the install, and it looks like it's the same version I have. They refuse to uninstall and reinstall it since another application is apparently relying on it at the moment. Is there anything else that I can do on my end other than rewrite the code to look at some way of parsing the .xslx file using its stream instead?

I have read through many of the other topics about this, and I can't seem to find anyone doing something differently.

Comment: Do you have the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the driver installed? It has to match your OS. If your OS is 64-bit, you can still install the 32-bit version of the driver but it will not be used properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was for the engineering team to complete "repair" on the installation from  add/remove programs.. This took forever to have them try, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb) seems to be about a similar error(granted it's for Access database), but the solution may be able to help with your problem:

In that thread the OP also installed the drivers you've linked ,that also failed so s/he installed these drivers:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

which worked apparently , try that.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search on MSDN and the alternative download for your issue is the [Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)